# gdb how to continue exec with stdin args with continue command

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

i am playing `ctf` and the program is checking if input is `proccess pid` then get shell now i getpid with **gdb-peda** by `getpid` command of gdb-peda how i can continue exec with stdin args that i will input the pid within it ?

i have tried 
`gdb> break *main+0`
`gdb> r`
`break point 1 + 0x0...`
`gdb> getpid`
`gdb> continue (pid)`
the problem that i cant pass input to the program while its already running it exited normally without my argument how to solve i need to stdin to the program after the breakpoint ?

Comment: From GDB, to pass argument `arg` from within, you use: `run arg` instead of `run` only.